# Is there a way to completely uninstall AppxPackages using CMD instead of Powershell?

Tags: windows, cmd, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall a few xbox app packages but the only way I have found to do this is using powershell.

Powershell is locked down on all the PC's I need to execute this on so that is not an option.

Any ideas?

`Get-AppxPackage -all Microsoft.XboxApp | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`
`Get-AppxPackage -all Microsoft.Xbox.TCUI | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`
`Get-AppxPackage -all Microsoft.XboxGameOverlay | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`
`Get-AppxPackage -all Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`
`Get-AppxPackage -all Microsoft.XboxIdentityProvider | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`
`Get-AppxPackage -all Microsoft.XboxSpeechToTextOverlay | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`

How can I achieve this in CMD only?

---

Comment: If by locked down you mean that execution of PowerShell _script files_ is prevented, you can still execute PowerShell code by calling [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, from `cmd.exe` / a batch file (`powershell.exe -c "Get-AppxPackage -all ..."`)

Comment: I already tried writing a batch file that calls the powershell script I wrote to execute.         Powershell.exe -File XboxAppsUninstall.ps1                                                                                    Executing powershell commands or powershell at all is locked by sysadmin

Comment: You cannot call a _script file_, but you can pass _commands_ to the `-c` (`-Command`) CLI parameter, as shown in my previous comment.

Comment: Never mind: While what I said is true in principle, the `AppX` module that must be loaded in order to execute `Get-AppXPackage` tries to load a `.ps1xml` file, which is also subject to the execution policy.

Comment: So is it basically impossible to truly uninstall this using CMD? I guess I could possibly delete the apps but was hoping to truly uninstall them without using PowerShell.

Comment: *Powershell.exe -File XboxAppsUninstall.ps1* And what happens if you try `powershell -exe bypass -file XboxAppsUninstall.ps1` ?

Comment: What are the reasons not to use PowerShell to uninstall?

Comment: @yacc: Note that this would only work if the execution policy isn't controlled via GPOs (which I presume to be the case here). GPO-controlled execution policies cannot be overridden with the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` CLI parameter, and also not via `Set-ExecutionPolicy`.

Comment: Although it won't uninstall it, you can deprovision the package using `dism` to prevent it from being installed on new users. I personally don't know what all the API does nor what the cmdlet does (*even after looking at the module*) to give you instructions on how to remove it off the system. I do know that theyre stored in *"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"* but don't know if removing it from there will fully uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

From your description I assume, you want to remove the package for all users. You need to open a CMD as admin first. Then you need to get the packagename of the app you want to uninstall

```
dism /online /get-provisionedappxpackages
```

now remove it with the following command (I used an XBox package for example)

```
dism /online /remove-provisionedappxpackage /packagename:Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_5.823.7272.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Comment: @mklement0, afaik they aren't different. They just get updated with every new Windows version. If you install the latest ADK on an older Windows, so you will have two different versions of dism.
But the appx stuff is there since early Win10 or maybe even 8 ;)

Comment: @mklement0 as far as I know, there is no difference to the usage on ARM. Even the documentation doesn't mention s.th. like that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-app-package--appx-or-appxbundle--servicing-command-line-options?view=windows-11

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and for the link. I don't know what I was smoking, but the AppX options are indeed working on my machine (I probably had a typo and was confused by the fact that `dism /?` doesn't show them).

Comment: However, based on the information in my next comment (I hope it's an accurate summary), you cannot do with `dism.exe` what the cmdlets such as `Get-AppXPackage` (such as used in the question) allow you to do.

Comment: [The `Dism.exe` options for AppX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-app-package--appx-or-appxbundle--servicing-command-line-options) are a subset of what's in the [`Dism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism) PowerShell module, which is focused on _provisioning_, i.e. managing apps for _future users_. By contrast, there are no options that correspond to the [`AppX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx) PowerShell module. The latter is required to manage packages for the _current_ / _all existing_ users.

Comment: you can remove packages for all users (including future users) with the /remove-provisionedappxpackage option. If you just want to remove an app for the current user, you might try dism /online /remove-package /packagename:YourApp

Comment: Thanks. `/remove-provisionedappxpackage` may be good enough, but its behavior differs from `Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers` (which is used in the question). By contrast - at least judging by [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-operating-system-package-servicing-command-line-options) - I wouldn't expect `/remove-package` (and the other options with "Package" but without "AppX" in the name) to work with AppX packages, given that these options (without `AppX` in the name) seemingly relate only to `.cab` and `.msu` files.